# Why does this exception happen? Lucene exception

Tags: java, database, lucene, connection-pooling

Our application is crashing every 2 hours or so and we are seeing a spike in database connections right before it. have not isolated the issue yet.

Can someone respond what the exception below really mean and can it spike DB connection issues.

Thank you.

```
org.compass.core.engine.SearchEngineException: Failed to open writer for sub index [premiumobjectmessage]; nested exception is org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: SimpleFSLock@/opt/compass/index/premiumobjectmessage/lucene-9af515d29c67db8ae587aab2becbc6f3-write.lock
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: SimpleFSLock@/opt/compass/index/premiumobjectmessage/lucene-9af515d29c67db8ae587aab2becbc6f3-write.lock
org.compass.core.engine.SearchEngineException: Failed to open writer for sub index [premiumobjectmessage]; nested exception is org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: SimpleFSLock@/opt/compass/index/premiumobjectmessage/lucene-9af515d29c67db8ae587aab2becbc6f3-write.lock
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: SimpleFSLock@/opt/compass/index/premiumobjectmessage/lucene-9af515d29c67db8ae587aab2becbc6f3-write.lock
org.compass.core.engine.SearchEngineException: Failed to open writer for sub index [premiumobjectmessage]; nested exception is org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: SimpleFSLock@/opt/compass/index/premiumobjectmessage/lucene-9af515d29c67db8ae587aab2becbc6f3-write.lock
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: SimpleFSLock@/opt/compass/index/premiumobjectmessage/lucene-9af515d29c67db8ae587aab2becbc6f3-write.lock
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stems from multiple threads/processes wanting to open the same `FSDirectory`. Maybe each thread that has its own DB connection also makes its own `IndexReader`, which would be a wrong approach. `IndexReader`s/`IndexSearcher`s must be pooled just like the DB connections themselves, preferrably using `NRTManager`.

Comment: Thank you Marko.  Will try to follow your instructions.